# Creating RDS database failed Reason: Cannot upgrade mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm following the instruction here to deploy my ruby on rails app on elastic beanstalks

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html

But I got following error when creating RDS database:

```
2014-04-19 18:35:49 INFO    Creating RDS database named: aa8njgjixa22x5. This may take a few minutes.
2014-04-19 18:45:17 ERROR   Creating RDS database: aa8njgjixa22x5 failed Reason: Cannot upgrade mysql from 5.6.13 to 5.5.33
2014-04-19 18:45:36 ERROR   Stack named 'awseb-e-qzjpemepuc-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED'  Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBRDSDatabase].
2014-04-19 18:45:39 INFO    Launched environment: drinkchatbackend-master. However, there were issues during launch. See event log for details.
```

Description :
2014-04-19 18:45:36 ERROR   Stack named 'awseb-e-qzjpemepuc-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED'  Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBRDSDatabase].
2014-04-19 18:45:17 ERROR   Creating RDS database: aa8njgjixa22x5 failed Reason: Cannot upgrade mysql from 5.6.13 to 5.5.33

Running "eb status --verbose" shows below

```
RDS Database: AWSEBRDSDatabase | aa8njgjixa22x5.cuokqzbpcqzr.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
Database Engine:    mysql 5.6.13
Allocated Storage:  5
Instance Class:     db.t1.micro
Multi AZ:       False
Master Username:    drinkchat
Creation Time:      2014-04-19 18:40:43
DB Instance Status: available
```

My .elasticbeanstalk/optionsettings080 config does not specifying 5.5.x

```
[aws:rds:dbinstance]
DBDeletionPolicy=Snapshot
DBEngine=mysql
DBInstanceClass=db.t1.micro
DBSnapshotIdentifier=drinkchatstaging-final-snapshot
DBUser=ebroot
```

Questions I have:

1. why it is trying to update to mysql 5.5.33?
2. how can I proceed investigation? I don;t see the application in
   https://console.aws.amazon.com
3. I can't find the DB instance in the Amazon RDS console.

Comment: I presume this has something to do with your elastic beanstalk config.  Its specifiying version 5.5.x when your instance is already at 5.6.x

Comment: My config does not specifying 5.5.x

[aws:rds:dbinstance]
DBDeletionPolicy=Snapshot
DBEngine=mysql
DBInstanceClass=db.t1.micro
DBSnapshotIdentifier=drinkchatstaging-final-snapshot
DBUser=ebroot

I think RDS supports 5.6.x already

Comment: I've run into a similar problem when trying to upgrade my RDS database from 5.5 to 5.6.  When I try to launch my elastic beanstalk app from an upgraded snapshot, it presents this error despite no explicit version restriction in my configuration.

Comment: You say you can't "see" the application.  Have you tried to run `eb console`?

Answer (score -1):

The work around I used was to not use elastic beanstalk's RDS configuration. instead just launch RDS manually and connect through my app.